# Issue when binding combobox and listbox to List (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, combobox, listbox, datasource

I'm trying to bind a ComboBox and a ListBox to a List(Of String) in Vb.Net (VS2013), this is for a WinForms application, the thing is that after setting the DataSource property on both the ComboBox and the ListBox, selecting one item on either one of them affects the other control, for example, after the controls have been populated with the information if I select an item from the ListBox, then the same item gets selected in the ComboBox, and this goes the same way for the ComboBox, if I select an item from it, then that item gets also selected in the ListBox, so my question is... how can I bind the combobox and listbox to the same List(Of String) without affecting the behavior on the controls, the purpose is to keep all the controls within that form syncronized based on the contents of the List, I declared the List in a module like this:

```
Public listaAreas As New List(Of String)
```

then the controls are populated like this on form load:

```
    cmbArea.DataSource = listaAreas
    lstAreas.DataSource = listaAreas
```

And I run this method whenever I need to update the information:

```
Private Sub RefreshLists()
    lstAreas.DataSource = Nothing
    lstAreas.DataSource = listaAreas

    cmbArea.DataSource = Nothing
    cmbArea.DataSource = listaAreas
End Sub
```

Please let me know if I'm missing some information, this is my first post but I think it is clear enough so you get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish here ... =)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up separate BindingSources and try using a BindingList(Of String) instead of just a List, which won't report item changes:

```
Private listaAreas As New BindingList(Of String)
Private cbSource As New BindingSource(listaAreas, String.Empty)
Private lbSource As New BindingSource(listaAreas, String.Empty)

Public Sub New()
  InitializeComponent()
  cmbArea.DataSource = cbSource
  lstAreas.DataSource = lbSource
End Sub
```

The same currency position is being used in your code, but by defining two separate binding sources, each one will have its own position property.

Comment: Thank you LarsTech, I made the changes and it is working fine now, but just to get your thoughts on this... how would you delete the selected items in the listbox?, I'm trying to delete them from the BindingList by using a For Each statement on lstAreas.SelectedItems but that raises an error due to the control being bound.

Comment: You can't remove the item from the ListBox.Items collection, you have to remove them from the listaAreas list: `listaAreas.Remove(lstAreas.SelectedItem)`.